# Docker: Use Host SSH Forwards in container

Tags: docker, ssh, port, portforwarding, tunnel

I try to access a *MS SQL Server* from within a Docker container.

The problem is, it is only reachable via an SSH tunnel that I can establish on my host machine. I use a local forward for `port` `1433`, that will automatically be established once I connect to the server.

Using *SquirrelSQL* for example, I can access the Server via `127.0.0.1:1433` with no problem.

But from within my docker container I am unable to do so.

I already tried to run the docker container with `--expose 1433 -p 127.0.0.1:1433:1433` but that didn't work out.

Host is running Ubuntu 16.04, the Docker Container is running on some sort of Debian.

Comment: What OS has your host and which docker technology (e.g. docker-machin with virtualbox, docker for mac etc.) are you using?

Comment: Host System is Ubuntu 16.04, Guest is some recent Debian.